# wordpress custom post type meta data does not displaying

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

Hello Everyone i am using [Easy-WordPress-Custom-Post-Types](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/Easy-WordPress-Custom-Post-Types) by [JeffreyWay](https://github.com/JeffreyWay) for crating custom post type for my post rating theme.the code for adding meta is as:`$review = new JW_Post_Type('Review',array('taxonomies' => array('category',        'post_tag')));`

`$review->add_meta_box('Admin Ratings', array(

'Rating' => array('select',array( '1.0','1.5','2.0','2.5','3.0','3.5','4.0','4.5','5.0'))));`

and for displaying data i'm using:echo get_post_meta( $postid, 'Admin Rating', true );
but it doesn't displays anything.

Answer (score 0):

Your meta names do not match. One is Admin Rating, the other is Admin Ratings.